# group an id on different dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-12

I am looking for a way that an id can be grouped in different months, since currently with the method that I have only the registered id is grouped in the first one that I enter and the other movements are integrated in that month even if they are from another month. For this I have the following code which I would like to edit to see if there is a possibility that an id can be grouped into different months.
For example: I have an id called bank and that has movement in March and April but the code that I have and that is shown below only groups in March and not in March and April as it should be.

```
<record id = "project_rc.count_view_search" model = "ir.ui.view">
    <field name = "name"> project_rc.cuenta.search </field>
    <field name = "model"> project_rc.account </field>
    <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
        <search string = "String ...">
            <field name = "date" />
            <group expand = "1" string = "Group By">
                    <filter string = "Date" name = "month" help = "help" context = "{'group_by': 'date'}" />
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Actually i didn't get you , applying  <filter string = "Date" name = "month" help = "help" context = "{'group_by': 'date'}" /> will be ok for you

Comment: but the problem that I have to filter by date one id remained only in one month and not in several in case I have movements in other months. For example: the bank account has an oct oct and november movement but with the code that it mentions it only groups in one month and not in both as it should be.

Comment: I enclose an image so you can see how it looks since in the link you can see which bank is grouped in the month of October but it also has dates in November and does not appear in November. https://ibb.co/GxGXCCj

Comment: What about a double group? `context="{'group_by': ['name', 'date: month']}"`

Comment: does not work "{'group_by': ['name', 'date: month']} I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined, is there another alternative?